# What is a standard command for printing a date in RFC-3339 format?

Tags: date

The `date` command doesn't offer such thing, which is kind of sad since RFC-3339 is the modern, widespread, sane format used everywhere (except in email which is neither modern nor sane).

My timezone offset is currently -08:00 so the simplest form of this command should print the current time as `2013-09-05T14:58:33.102-08:00`.

Comment: Which _standard_ (s) are you interested in?

Comment: I personally am fine with GNU but in the grand scheme of things it really should be broader than that. It should also come with a reasonable default (short option, millisecond precision) and have a way to specify the subsecond precision (number of digits other than 0 or 9).

Comment: It's *not* a sane format: the total absence of whitespace makes it unnecessarily hard for humans to read.  You should use the slight variation `2013-09-05 14:58:33.102 -0800` except when there is some reason why spaces must not be used at all.

Comment: I was comparing it to the mail date format (RFC 822, 2822) which is hard to read for both humans and machines.

Answer (score 49):

It seems like you can do several formats using the switch to the GNU implementation of `date` (version 5.90 or above), `--rfc3339=`.

#### Examples

```
$ date --rfc-3339=date
2014-03-19

$ date --rfc-3339=seconds
2014-03-19 18:00:05-04:00

$ date --rfc-3339=ns
2014-03-19 18:00:08.179780629-04:00
```

If you want the `T` to be added, as a hack:

```
$ date --rfc-3339=seconds | sed 's/ /T/'
2014-03-19T18:35:03-04:00
```

If you want it in milliseconds:

```
$ date --rfc-3339=ns | sed 's/ /T/; s/\(\....\).*\([+-]\)/\1\2/g'
2014-03-19T18:42:52.362-04:00
```

#### References

- [Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-12)

Comment: These days, no hack is needed to get the 'T'.  The `--iso-8601' option accepts the same arguments as `--rfc-3339`, and includes the 'T' in its output.

Comment: BTW, RFC3339 *requires* uppercase `T` in expression. If it's missing, it's not standard (RFC3339) compliant. ISO8601 allows more variants, and more ambiguous and harder to parse and process.

Comment: Sed part `s/\(\....\).*-/\1-/g` should be `s/\(\....\).*\([+-]\)/\1\2/g` to also work east of the Atlantic.

Comment: @svante - thanks for the detail, fixed.

Comment: @Eonil that is actually not correct, the RFC3339 states: `NOTE: ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".` While RFC3339 allows you to use a space instead. Read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt Section 5.6

Comment: @rwenz3l My fault. I just read only ABNF part and missed the notes. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Eonil No problem, it _is_ quite confusing that they have extra prose contradicting the BNF. The prose also says you are allowed to use lowercase `t` and `z` instead of uppercase!

Answer (score 19):

With GNU `date` (5.90 or above):

```
$ TZ=America/Anchorage date '+%FT%T.%N%:z'
2014-03-19T14:29:31.041119357-08:00
```

Replace `%N` with `%3N` for milliseconds, `%6N` for micro-seconds...

AFAIK, none of the POSIX, Unix or LSB specifications specify any command that can display times with sub-second granularity, but the fractional part is optional in RFC 3339.

POSIX/Unix/LSB strftime supports `%z` to display the TZ offset as `-0800`, so the most portable you're probably going to get is:

```
 $ TZ=America/Anchorage perl -MPOSIX -le '$t = strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%T%z",
   localtime; $t =~ s/..$/:$&/; print $t'
 2014-03-19T14:30:23-08:00
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also format time according to [RFC3339 ( ISO8601 )](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) easier:

```bsh
$ date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
2016-11-08T08:52:55Z
```

**NOTE:** This format is also used in the [Label Schema Convention RC 1.0](http://label-schema.org/rc1/)

Comment: That's not a valid RFC3339. Eran's answer of 
```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z
```
is correct and less characters. If you want in UTC pass -u flag, which will zero out the timezone offset.

Comment: With the `-u` flag this answer is correct, right?

Comment: @briceburg why is this not valid RFC3339? According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6 it seems to be correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 13):

How about good old :

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%z
2015-10-29T14:47:06+0200
```

Comment: Where is the time zone information?

Comment: This works both on mac and linux 'date'

Comment: How about milliseconds?

Comment: @MartinJambon it's a good question, I don't think mac date supports nanoseconds. In gnu it's %N3

Comment: quick note here, without opening up the RFC, the timezone segment, `0200` is missing a colon, which may break some systems which require it.

Comment: @MikeMackintosh's note is pertinent; the output shown here is *not* a legal RFC 3339 date. The colon in the timezone segment is required for RFC 3339; see the definition of `time-numoffset` at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6.

Comment: This could be simplified to `date -u "+%FT%TZ"`. Example output: `2021-03-20T18:23:14Z`.

Answer (score 9):

GNU `date` has the ISO-8601 format built in - isn't that quite close or even idential to RFC-3339?

```
1065 % date --iso-8601=seconds
2014-03-19T16:51:16-0600
```

Comment: ISO-8601 allows different formattings of dates and times, but I think the OP is asking specifically for *W3C Date* format *"Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)"* - [W3C Date and Time Formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Local date only:"
date '+%Y-%m-%d'
echo
echo "Local date and time:"
date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' | sed 's@^.\{22\}@&:@'
echo
echo "UTC date and time:"
date -u '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

These commands are POSIX-compatible, with the exception of the `%z` conversion specification. However, `%z` is widely supported and works the same way in Linux, MacOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, DragonFlyBSD, Solaris, Minix and Haiku. It also works with the tools in Busybox, Toybox and sbase (the suckless.org base system utilities). Since `%z` outputs the timezone offset in `±HHMM` format, we need the `sed` pipe to add a colon and change it to `±HH:MM`.

NOTE: The Heirloom project's `date` command has incompatible `%z` output: it does not print a `+` sign.

Answer (score 0):

For UTC you can use.

```
date -u --rfc-3339=ns | sed -r 's/ /T/; s/\.([0-9]{3}).*/\.\1Z/'
```